# Apply Effect same like xls or xlsx in csv using phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am Exporting reports to csv and xls using PhpExcel. I can see the effects like color, Grouping, Width, Wraptext in cell, Font style, Font size, Bold etc.... in the xls format but when I pass this to csv writer object then data are properly placed in cells but no effects are applying in csv. I am using below code for export to csv.

I have tried with 2 different ways but the result was the same

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
```

and another

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);


$objWriter->setDelimiter(',');
$objWriter->setEnclosure('');
$objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because CSV files only store data, not style.... you simply cannot store the fact that a block of text should be bold or fixed width of wrapping or even merged cells in a csv file. PHPExcel can't change that, it's just the way CSV files are, and why you need to use another format if you do want styling in your output.